# Calculate Vth between A and B

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHTBof.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this circuit, I am asked to calculate Thevenin Voltage Vth between A and B.

This is the first time I am asked to calculate Vth between two distant point and I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What difference do you think "distant" makes?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany When point are above each other, you just have to "remove" what's between then and calculate Vth using Kirchhoff law. Bet here we can't just do that i think..If only we can move point A or B.

Comment: In a schematic we assume all the dots and lines that are in contact are at the same voltage.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You mean, i can just assume that A above B and proceed to find Vth?

Comment: The voltage all along the bottom is the same as at B, and all along the top is the same as A. But above or not make no difference in a schematic, you can rotate it 90 degrees and it won't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you are asked to find Thevenin voltage across  R3, R2, R1, Voltage source or Current source, which are all same:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxi9Cq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because the potential is the same on all points shorted along the wire.

Comment: I've tried another way to do this, can you please check if it's the right way to go?

Comment: Can you understand now ??

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRGSgO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We will calculate Vab using millman law, we get Vab = (1/R1 + 1/R2 + I1 + 1/R3) / (1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3)

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: why are you calculating anything? ... `Vab = V1` ....

Comment: you are thinking in complicated manner which is unfortunately wrong as well